# Review Schedule Task Code In Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am writing a code to be scheduled to run occasionally. I want to remove records of users who have their details on the users table but does not have their records in the profiles table as well. I am thinking about removing the by their id, but I am not sure how I can make the match. profiles migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('gender',5);
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); // When a profile is deleted- his corresponding associated id details are deleted as well.
        $table->tinyInteger('age')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('goals')->nullable();;
        $table->string('activityType')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken(); // for remember me feature.
    });
}
```

Users migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('username',20)->unique(); 
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have started to write the query, yet I am not sure how to proceed.

```
 public function handle()
    {
    // type the query to get users that have no data in their profiles.

        $empty_profile=App\Profile:::where('id','')->get;
        $user_id=App\User::where('id')
    }
```

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your example is not exactly clear to me (and I wonder why there would be users without profiles in the first place?) I think this is what you need:

```
public function handle()
{
    $empty_profiles = App\User::doesntHave('profile')->delete();
}
```

This will work if the models are correctly connected see also:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Comment: hey, it is because I am inserting data to 'users' table, and then inserting data to 'profiles' table in another page, so I have created 2 separate models.  Not the best approach when I look back.

It is looking good now, thanks! I am wondering why this is not shown in the laravel documentation.

Now, I need  to remove those records from the db, what eloquent/query builder should I use?

Comment: I am trying to delete in php artisan tinker
`$empty_profiles->delete();`

But I am getting an error instead:
`BadMethodCallException with message 'Method delete does not exist.`

Comment: See updated answer (->get() became ->delete()). This should work. Let me know.